# css - white line between border and content after scaling

Tags: html, css, scaling, antialiasing

I created simple example:

- parent div with black border
- inner div with black background

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="scale: 0.75">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 495px; border: 7px solid black; overflow: hidden">
        <div style="background: black; color: white; padding: 10px">test</div>
        other test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As parent div has no padding - there should be no gaps between border and inner div. And it works in normal case. BUT when I'm adding scaling - it immediately adds white lines around the content.
See example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tk7vsbpf/

I suppose this may be related to antialiasing in browser, but I still need some solution as unfortunately I have to scale my component.
Maybe someone has ideas?

I tried to add background for parent div and it works - it removes the lines, but issue is - I need BG of other color there.
I also tried to use box-shadow, but it doesn't fix the issue fully. It removes lines in some places, but not everywhere.

Comment: are you talking about this hairline, barely visible grayish line? https://imgur.com/a/T66jDj3   if so, yes im pretty sure that artifact results from non-integer subpixel boundaries. and in my experience its unavoidable on certain screen+GPU setups, and tends to get more obvious the smaller your screen resolution is. It can be quite maddening. My go to way of hiding it is simply to overlap adjacent divs that are exhibiting the issue by at least one pixel, but as you alluded to that is not always a sensible solution.

Comment: What is more interesting, I tried to add "position: relative; left: -2px; top: -2px" for child element. so it really moved 2 pixels to top-left, BUT the white line is still there! So now border do intersect with child element and still there is a divider.

Answer (score 3):

Why did the box shadow not work? If you do `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1)` it works fine and removes the white line. Look:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="scale: 0.75">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 495px; border: 7px solid black; overflow: clip">
        <div style="background: black; color: white; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);">test</div>
        other test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. So yep it seems like working and I spent some time trying to adapt this solution to my case and didn't succeed. And found one more detail. So in my case parent container also has "overflow: hidden" style as it's contents can be longer than height. And this again breaks this solution. I still see the line. 
I'll update my original question with this additional style

Comment: Even if there is `overflow: hidden` I believe this should still work. I'll update the snippet and check. If it doesn't, why would this matter, its just a small detail :P

Comment: The width of this white line really depends on scale and browser zoom. So for some cases it becomes really noticeable and the whole rendered component looks awful with these lines.